# Spring boot, Jackson Json Issue while serializing and deserializing

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

For some use case, I need to convert one POJO to another POJO with the different fields name. I tried using Jackson object mapper. It worked in some extends. However end result is not what I expected.

```
public class JacksonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        User user = new User("Deepak", "111", "Singapore");
        UserMap newUser = mapper.convertValue(user, UserMap.class);
        System.out.println("SOUT: " + newUser);
        System.out.println("Jackson: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(newUser));
    }
}

class User {

    User(String name, String id, String address){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.address = address;
    }

    String name;
    String id;
    String address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}

class UserMap implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;

    private Map<String, Object> meta = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> any() {
        return meta;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, Object value) {
        meta.put(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserMap{" +
                "name_new='" + name + '\'' +
                ", meta=" + meta.keySet().stream().map(x-> x+ ":: "+ meta.get(x)).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) +
                '}';
    }
}
```

If you run, the output would be :

SOUT: UserMap{name_new='Deepak', meta=address:: Singapore, id:: 111}

Jackson: {"name":"Deepak","address":"Singapore","id":"111"}

I am using Springboot which internally uses jackson serializer. It converts the **newUser** object to normal user class again. I want to serialize string in the way class constructed. I want the output in SOUT format.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood what the `@JsonAnyGetter/@JsonAnySetter` pair will, in effect, do.

It allows you to create a *almost dynamic* bean, with mandatory as well as voluntary fields. In your case, the name would be mandatory, and all other fields voluntary.

What goes on under the hood is **not** that your `UserMap` gets converted to a `User`. What you see is a serialized UserMap, but since it has the same fields and values as the corresponding `User` instance, their serialized forms look identical.

Comment: I understand how its working. For some requirement, i need the way is to construct object class. Right now i am creating a POJO and feel all these data before serialization.

Comment: @DeepakSharma I don't understand what you mean by " i need the way is to construct object class". Also, what is wrong with creating a POJO and filling in the data before serializing it?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the auto serialization and deserialization to work using the default Spring boot beans. In the end, this worked well for me after including Project Lombok and apache BeanUtils:

```
@ToString() @Getter() @Setter() @NoArgsConstructor()
public class User {
    private String email;
    private String bio;
    private String image;
    private String displayName;
    private String userId;
    private long lat;
    private long lng;

    public User(String json) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        User u = om.readValue(json, User.class);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(this, u);
    }
}
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/download_beanutils.cgi
https://projectlombok.org/